# concatenate int to str in a selenium xpath loop

Tags: string, for-loop, xpath, integer

The python selenium automation needs to select checkboxes with id module from 290000 to 300000.

To create a for loop we need to place an int inside an xpath

```
x = 290000    

if x < 300000:
    xpath_string = '//*[@id="module-' + x + '"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/button/img'.format(str(x))
    loginLinker = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_string).click()

print("Successful")
```

> Error:  xpath_string = '//*[@id="module-' + x +
> '"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/button/img'.format(str(x))
> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
x = 290000    

while x < 300000:
    xpath_string = '//*[@id="module-' + str(x) + '"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/button/img'
    loginLinker = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_string).click()
    x = x+1
    print("Successful")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```